# Unable to create custom image name in Spring Boot 2.5.5 with Docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, maven, microservices

I am developing small Spring Boot micro-service application. I am facing an issue when I am trying to create custom Spring image to deploy into Docker engine. To create new custom image I am using configuration element in Maven plugin section of my POM file.

> Error : Failed to execute goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.5:build-image
> (default-cli) on project BankModule: Execution default-cli of goal
> org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.5:build-image
> failed: Unable to parse image reference
> "kolludocker/ms1-BankModule:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT". Image reference must be
> in the form '[domainHost:port/][path/]name[:tag][@digest]', with
> 'path' and 'name' containing only [a-z0-9][.][_][-] -> [Help 1]
> [ERROR]

The `pom.xml` file :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>com.kollu.BankModule</groupId>
    <artifactId>BankModule</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    </version>
    <name>BankModule</name>
    <description>BankModule SpringBoot and MicroServices project
    </description>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>2020.0.4</spring-cloud.version> <!-- Eureka server -->
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Eureka server -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency> <!-- Inbuild LoadBalancer dependency-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Fault tolerance- Circuit Breakers with resilience4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.resilience4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>resilience4j-spring-boot2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Distributed Tracing(To generate unique id per each logger) - sleuth,RabbitMQ,ZipKin --> <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-sleuth</artifactId> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId> <artifactId>spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin</artifactId> </dependency> <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId> </dependency> -->
        <!-- mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/… -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Oracle -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId> <!-- <scope>12.2.0.1</scope> -->
            <version>12.2.0.1</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
        </dependency> <!-- Swagger api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Field/ Input values validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies> <!-- Eureka server -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.5</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->
                <configuration>
                    <image>
                        <name>kolludocker/ms1-${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
                    </image>
                    <pullPolicy>IF_NOT_PRESENT</pullPolicy>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Error : Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.5:build-image (default-cli) on project BankModule: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.5.5:build-image failed: Unable to parse image reference "kolludocker/ms1-BankModule:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT". Image reference must be in the form '[domainHost:port/][path/]name[:tag][@digest]', with 'path' and 'name' containing only [a-z0-9][.][_][-] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]

Comment: Can you provide your `plugin` section or your `pom` file?

Comment: This `regular expression`  `[a-z0-9][.][_][-]` means that does not accept `upper case`. Modify the name of your `artifactId` and your version to see what will happens. This post could help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014089/docker-repository-name-component-must-match

Comment: It's working fine now. Great!! Thank you so much. Looking forward to get help from you.

Answer (score 7):

The artifact id has capital letters in its name. The error given is telling:

'path' and 'name' containing only `[a-z0-9][.][_][-]`

Once you make the artifact id "BankModule" to "bank-module", this will work.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried lower case as well as setting it as a property? This work well for me (v2.6.3) and is IMHO more elegant/compact:

```
<properties>
    <spring-boot.build-image.imageName>io.bla/example/bla</spring-boot.build-image.imageName>
</properties>
```

Doc: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#build-image.customization